# Bootstrap - How do make nested columns match width of outer col

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

[This form](https://jsfiddle.net/battlfrog/reohda5t/5/) (expand the result panel so there are only 2 rows), the first row has a select and a text field.  The second row has a select, then 2 text fields nested inside a column.  It has to be this way because of show/hide of other fields inside this second column.

The two text fields do not take up the full width, but I need them to match the width of the text box in the first row.

```
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <select class="form-control col-md-4"><option value="1">Hi There</option></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control"/>  
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <select class="form-control col-md-4"><option value="1">Hi There</option></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>  
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>  
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You abuse the column class. It must have it's own div. Whats happening is that the `form-group` class removes the margin of the columns. Also (and this is not documented as far as i know) the `form-group` inside a form-horizontal acts as a row itself. Try this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select class="form-control col-md-4"><option value="1">Hi There</option></select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"/>  
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Here your example rewritten: https://jsfiddle.net/reohda5t/4/

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. The side by side inputs have to stay nested in the col-md-8, because they have a hide/show effect.  See the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/battlfrog/reohda5t/5/

Comment: @BattlFrog then simply follow the documentation on how to nest column normally an here you go ;) : https://jsfiddle.net/reohda5t/7/

Comment: So it looks like the rule is the nested columns have to be in a row?